# jQuery - Slide to id .stop(); equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have this code for sliding down to each section on the page. The nav link has an id which links to the corresponding class. This works perfectly except if you click a nav button and then quicky click another it will continue to play out the animation. This isn't too bad.. but if you're mashing the buttons it really freaks out.

I tried using .stop(); but as expected, this stops the animation all together and jumps to the section. Ideally I wish it to go to stop animating wherever it is and continue to the selected section.

I have NO idea how to do this, so jQuery wizards please help!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJLHg/14/)

```
$('.nav-item').on('click',function(e){
        var scrollSpeed = 1000;
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var goTo =  $('div.'+ id).offset().top;

        e.preventDefault();
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use stop as you have said before

```
$("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XRGkd/